# I want to read an array but when i press the play button nothing happens! what it is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

i have a problem with scanner! i don't know why i can't read the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hotel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String []name = new String[10]; //first array
        double [][]money = new double[12][2];//second array 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            name[i] = input.next(); //here is my problem
        }
        for(int k=0; k<12; k++) {
            for(int j=0; j<12; j++) {
                if ((j==1)||(j==2)||(j==10)) {
                    money[k][j]=-1;
                }
                else {
                    money[k][j]= input.nextDouble(); //and here 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? You can't read the `array`? What does that mean? Are you trying to read the `array` or read from the keyboard?

Comment: Are you providing input on `System.in` (e.g. typing something into the console?)

Comment: money array's second dimension is 2 or 12? if it is 2 why do you check `j == 2` or `j == 10`

Comment: i want to read from the keyboard. Forget about the dimensions! How can i use the scanner to read from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you're accessing `money[12][2]` which doesn't exists since you declared money as `new double[12][2]`. I suspect you might wanted to create money as `double[] money = new double[12][12];`